# View work requests in queue of .net thread pool

Tags: .net, windbg

In WinDbg I can see that thread pool has 4005 work requests in the queue. Can I somehow see what these requests are?

```
0:000> !threadpool
CPU utilization: 100%
Worker Thread: Total: 301 Running: 301 Idle: 0 MaxLimit: 1023 MinLimit: 1
Work Request in Queue: 4005
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 8
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 6 Free: 0 MaxFree: 2 CurrentLimit: 6 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 1
```

Comment: Is `!dumpheap -type WaitCallback` helpful? It's not necessarily accurate, because you may have WaitCallbacks that have been created but not added to the thread pool yet.

Comment: @Thomas: not much, number of WaitCallback much less than number of work requests: `0:004> !dumpheap -type WaitCallback -stat
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
68b727b8       25          800 System.Threading.WaitCallback`

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying.

Comment: How about `!dumpheap -type QueueUserWorkItemCallback`?

Comment: @Steve Johnson: none found